# Issue when installing the data.table package in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to install the data.table package in R but I'm getting the error:

```
> install.packages("data.table")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/*/3.5’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
           binary source needs_compilation
data.table 1.12.6 1.12.8              TRUE

installing the source package ‘data.table’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/data.table_1.12.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4948391 bytes (4.7 MB)
downloaded 4.7 MB

The system cannot find the path specified.
* installing *source* package 'data.table' ...
** package 'data.table' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-35~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG       -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=generic -c assign.c -o assign.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc: not found
make: *** [assign.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'data.table'
* removing 'C:/Users/*/win-library/3.5/data.table'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘C:\Users\*\Local\Temp\1\RtmpGUTU7i\downloaded_packages’
```

I am using R for windows 3.5.3, Rstudio 1.1.456, and Rtools 3.4.4 Versions.

Comment: When you ran `install.packages("data.table")` did it ask you if you wanted to install from source? You should say no to that. It would be easier to use the binaries. What about `install.packages("data.table", type="binary")`?

Comment: Thankyou very much  MrFlick
It is working after installing using command
install.packages("data.table", type="binary") ,But getting this warning while trying to load the package
> library(data.table)

data.table 1.12.8 using 2 threads (see ?getDTthreads).  Latest news: r-datatable.com

Comment: That's not a warning. That's just a start up message. If you'd rather not see that you can use the `suppressPackageStartupMessages()` function